# Label of the secondary y axis lines on the secondary y axis values

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a dual y axis plot using the following code:

```
plot(dataset1, col="black", ylab="Height (ft)", main = "W7R001")
par(new = TRUE)
points(dataset5, col="red", pch = ".", xlab="", ylab="", axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 4)
mtext(side = 4, "Height (m)")
```

My issue now is that, on the secondary plot, the label of the secondary y axis lies on the secondary y axis values. How do I fix or avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shift the label on the second y-axis with the line parameter. You also need to increase the right margin of the plot.

```
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.1) #increase plot margins to the right
plot(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, xlab = "", ylab="LABEL")
axis(side = 4)
mtext(side = 4, "LABEL", line = 3) #shift position of the label
```

[image]